# Revit API Copy Elements Duplicates View

Tags: revit-api

I have a simple method that is supposed to copy a view from one model to another with any view specific elements.  Here is the method:

```
void HandleViewTransfer(View view, Document sourceDoc, Document targetDoc)
{

    var newViewId = ElementTransformUtils
        .CopyElements(sourceDoc, new[] { view.Id }, targetDoc, null, new CopyPasteOptions()).First();
    var newView = targetDoc.GetElement(newViewId) as View;

    var viewElements = new FilteredElementCollector(sourceDoc).OwnedByView(view.Id).ToElementIds();
    ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements(view, viewElements, newView, null, new CopyPasteOptions());
}
```

When I run this it works... sort of.  I have a sample model with a drafting view called 'DraftingViewTransferSource' that I'm testing transferring to a new file.  When I run this I get 2 drafting views in the target document 'DraftingViewTransferSource' and 'DraftingViewTransferSource1'.  The first is empty and the second looks exactly like I want (with all the view specific elements in it).

This would suggest to me that it's trying to transfer the view itself twice and the second one is renaming.  However, I have looked through the debugging and it's only being called once, the view ID is correct in the transfer itself, and the view id is NOT in the second transfer (of the view specific elements) so I'm not sure why it's showing up twice.

I also though maybe the view specific elements bring in the view, but that can't be the case because that call requires the view to be created already.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**
This is being done in a single transaction, but I've also tried to wrap the view copy and the element copy in separate transactions and to wrap one with a sub-transaction, both with the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you are just copying the views and not also a view type by mistake? Anyway, I [asked](https://autodesk.slack.com/archives/C0SR6NAP8/p1701419766323599)  the devteam for you as well.

Comment: The only id's I'm passing are the ones returned from the `FilteredElementCollector` which should be getting view specific elements in that view.  If that is getting the view type of that view as well that's even more broken...  I didn't check every ID but I'm pretty certain it's just view specific elements and not any views or view types.  Thanks for the ping to the dev team.

Comment: Haha. The filtered element collector will return both view and associated view type if you ask it for the view category. You need to explicitly remove the view type if you are only interested in the view. And so on and so forth. Please take a careful look at each single element that you process and check whether it ought to be removed by additional filters or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some more experimentation I think this is a case of some really confusing documentation.  In case it helps someone else out, here is what I did:

- I tried commenting out the part where it copies the view itself over and just did the part where it copies the elements within the view (I manually created the target view and found it by name).  I made a fortunate mistake here and messed up the view name so it wasn't the same.  When running this, it still brought in everything, but with the view name from the source document, leaving the one I had messed up there and empty.
- From the above it seemed like the target view does not matter at least when copying from one model to another.  To test this I just found the first floor plan in the target project and selected that as the target view.  Running this gives the exact same result, the view and all it's contents are copied to the target model with the correct name, etc.  Nothing at all happens to the target view that I could see.
- After this I decided to try just copying the elements and view using the other overload that copies from one document to another, even though the documentation sounds like this shouldn't work for view specific elements.  It worked!  Same deal, I passed the id's of the view and the elements in it and everything copied over just how I wanted it.

So in the end, that seems to be the answer, just use the document to document overload.  The updated method would just be:

```
void HandleViewTransfer(View view, Document sourceDoc, Document targetDoc)
{
    var viewElements = new FilteredElementCollector(sourceDoc)
        .OwnedByView(view.Id)
        .ToElementIds();
    ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements(sourceDoc, viewElements.Concat(view.Id).ToList(), targetDoc, null, new CopyPasteOptions());
}
```

This works, however the documentation for this method specifically states: `This method can be used for copying non-view specific elements only. For copying view-specific elements, use the view-specific form of the CopyElements method.`  To me, this means that you shouldn't use this for copying out view contents, you should use the method that takes a source and target view.  The documentation for THAT method states `The destination view can be in the same document as the source view.`  While that doesn't specifically say it can be in another document it implies that between documents is fine and maybe even intended as the primary use.  This is why I started where I did.  As described above, this works but seems to just take the document from the given view and ignore the view itself, so there is no real function of the target view except to tell it which document to target.

If anyone has a better answer or explanation I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for raising and researching this. We have submitted a development ticket **REVIT-216102** in order to take a closer look.

Comment: Also to add to your ticket.  This seems to be different in 2024 from 2023 and before.  Earlier versions throw an exception when you include view specific elements in the transfer as shown in my answer so you DO have to copy the view and THEN copy the view specific elements using the view to view transfer.  2024 you CAN'T do it that way, you have to do it as shown in my answer.